# android:inputType not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inputtype

Below code opens numeric keyboard on some devices.Maximum occurrings are on premium devices.

The xml file only have a text view and the below EditText.The activity opens by `startActivityForResult`.

Also in this activity we have written        `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);` so that previous keyboards gets hidden. But in any case is that possible that previous keyboard that is used by mobile number of previous activity is retained?

Or is this any issue with custom keyboards?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCompleteAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/hintCompleteAddress"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    bind:font="@{AppConstants.OpenSansRegular}"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextnocorner"
    android:lines="4"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Comment: Observed only on samsung devices

Answer (score 2):

Change your `inputType` to this

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
```